# Laravel Command - Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist

Tags: laravel

I created a command in Laravel to run on a task schedule.

Here is the command logic:

```
public function handle()
{
    $commentNotifications = CommentNotification::where('task_performed', 0)
    ->get();
    
    foreach ($commentNotifications as $commentNotification) {
        //blah blah
    }
    
    $commentNotifications->update(['task_performed' => 1]);


    $this->comment(sprintf('Completed %d CommentNotification(s)', $commentNotifications->count()));
}
```

however this returned the following error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::update does not exist.

So I tried this instead:

```
    $commentNotifications->task_performed = 1;
    $commentNotifications->save();
```

but this returned:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You can't update collection. use ```$commentNotification->update(['task_performed' => 1]);``` in the loop.

Comment: But I have thousands of records in that loop. That would cause thousands of queries...

Comment: In this case, make a new query and update it like so: ```CommentNotification::where('task_performed', 0)->update(['task_performed' => 1]);```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here. One is your understanding of the Eloquent collection, and then your need to update multiple records with a single query.

Firstly, a collection is just a set of in-memory records that you can iterate through. The Eloquent collection is just an extension of that, where those records are pulled from a database, and typically has a set of models as the underlying items. It also has some extra methods to work with those models.

However, it is not directly tied to the database at all. This means that functions like update wouldn't work, and hence they do not exist.

For your need to update multiple records in the collection, you don't need to load them into memory first (unless you want to use them elsewhere). Simply create a query using the Builder, and call update on that query

```
CommentNotification::where('task_performed', 0)->update(['task_performed' = 1]);
```

This will create the expected SQL query:

```
UPDATE comment_notifications SET task_performed = 1 WHERE task_performed = 0;
```

Edit - To answer your query about the mass update:

If you need to only update a subset of records, you simply need to add a extra filter to the update

```
CommentNotification::whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
    ->where('task_performed', 0)
    ->update(['task_performed' = 1]);
```

This will update only the records with those IDs, and then only if the task is not performed. How you source the array of id values will be up to you.

Comment: I thought of using a mass update. However, the command may take a long time to run through the foreach. By the time it's over, new CommentNotifications may have been added to the database. These would not go through the for loop but their status would be updated to task_performed = 1.

Comment: Then you need to filter them to just entries you need to update. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you are using get() returns a collection therefore you cannot use update and save since they are methods of the eloquent model class
use first() to get the first model instead of a collection , or use the update inside the foreach to update each item in your collections .

save() and update() exist in *Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;*

for example

```
foreach ($commentNotifications as $commentNotification) {
        $commentNotification->update(['task_performed' => 1]);
    }
```

Comment: This will cause a database query on every loop. I do not want that.

Comment: i think this explains a bit why you faced the error , but you can still use the update directly as suggested in the first comment

Answer (score 0):

`->get()` returns a collection.
Use a loop to [update](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#updates):

```
public function handle()
{
    $commentNotifications = CommentNotification::where('task_performed', 0)
    ->get();
    
    foreach ($commentNotifications as $commentNotification) {
        $commentNotification->task_performed = 1;
        $commentNotification->save();
    }
    
    $this->comment(sprintf('Completed %d CommentNotification(s)', $commentNotifications->count()));
}
```

Or, use [Mass Updates](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-updates).

```
CommentNotification::where('task_performed', 0)->update(['task_performed' => 1]);
```

Comment: I thought of using a mass update. However, the command may take a long time to run through the foreach. By the time it's over, new CommentNotifications may have been added to the database. These would not go through the for loop but their status would be updated to task_performed = 1.